# Purpose of "Edit:" line in post

Tags: discussion, posting

Many questions/answers use something like "Edit:" to mark a part of the post as "added later." Example:

> The result is `4` because `sizeof(int)  == 2` on your machine, so `sizeof(int) * 2 == 2 * 2 == 4`.
>
> **Edit:**
>   As @cad noted, `sizeof(int)` is **implementation-defined**.

<sub>**I couldn't find an example so fast. Replacing it by a better** ***and real*** **example is appreciated!**</sub>

What's the purpose of that and what are its benefits?
And following from that, should editors remove it or not?

---

<sub>I remember to have asked myself this very question and to have figured out an advantage but I can't remember it anymore. :(</sub>

Comment: It's noise and should be deleted.  Often you see this because the OP is not very thorough with their edit to incorporate the clarification into the post.  An `Edit` doesn't really help anyone who is seeing the current revision.

Comment: @cad then yeah, it's noise, like ryanyuyu said. Although I'd disagree with the cause- I believe it's just as often a result of a user who is more used to the environment of a forum, which, at least the ones I've seen, often times doesn't have an "edit" history per post, if they even indicate a post was edited at all. Our "edited x ago" message at the bottom of a post more than serves the purpose of an "edit:" comment in a post, so you should edit that out when you see it. (And potentially reorganize the post to make sense and flow better, if needed.)

Comment: What's the purpose of excessive `<sub>`s in questions?

Comment: @KerrekSB To make you ask the purpose of it. Looks like it worked this time! (Serious answer: Often times, it's used for footnotes and side notes. In this case, it is both times used for a "side note" effect. Both points in the `<sub>` tags are side notes that are related to the question, but not an actual part of the question's main point.)

Comment: [MSE duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/).

Comment: @KerrekSB I used it to highlight sentences only loosely related to the question. How else should I have expressed that? Feel free to edit.

Comment: It's just a lazy way of adding more content to the post without having to make it **fit** into the flow of the post correctly.

Comment: I think Kevin B was more referring to the "Edit:" lines your post addresses, since that is how some people use them.

Comment: the "Edit:" text is a lazy way of making the rest of the content of the edit fit into the question, is what i mean. The correct thing to do would be to add that information into the flow of the post without the "Edit:" header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the purpose of that and what are its benefits?

The "purpose" would be that the OP lets anyone who has seen the question/answer before know that it has been edited with additional information that might help them answer the question, while they couldn't (or wouldn't) before because it was lacking that (perhaps important) information.

There are no real benefits though and it's rather pointless to put "Edit" in your question/answer, since the editing system already says "Edited by ... X minutes ago" under the question/answer (assuming it's a few minutes old and it's not just a spelling correction or something).

> And following from that, should editors remove it or not?

Yes, it's unnecessary noise to the question/answer, it does not add anything constructive and people see the "Edited by" widget anyway, so there's really no point in it being there.