# Should we silently update an Answer?

Tags: discussion

Last year I posted an [answer on How to modify outgoing Request Headers with Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936481/816213). If you can see there is a **PS** and **PPS** statement. Those were made as Edits to the answer.

Whenever I want to make an edit, I feel the need to specify that there is something which is changed either by comment or by making PS statement like in above answer.

For example: Snapshot in above answer is old and I want to update it to the latest visual. Should I make a comment that I have updated the screenshot or add another PPS ?

Comment: When you edit, there is a place for detailing why the changes were made (edit summary). These are shown in the revision view (when you click the "edited at ..." link).

Comment: Honestly, I don't care for stuff like "EDIT" or "P.S." because it's needlessly distracting most of the time.  I prefer just adding a horizontal divider and a notes section at the bottom.  The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27936481/revisions) will track edits for you.

Comment: See: [Purpose of “Edit:” line in post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310159/4639281). "PS", "PPS" and other such nonsense is noise and should never exist in a post.

Comment: @TinyGiant: PS and PPS can be useful: If it goes off on some kind of tangent to the main question. Though "as an aside" or some such are equally good for that.

Comment: Well.... If it is going of on some kind of tangent to the main question, is the tangent not noise as well? @Deduplicator

Comment: @TinyGiant: Not neccessarily, it depends on the details.

Comment: Well, I'd have to see an example of when that would be acceptable. I can't think of any reason for it. @Deduplicator

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Should I make a comment that I have updated the screenshot or add another PPS ?

Do neither, just update the answer.  Postfixing the edit with a postscript is just noise, as is a comment.  If anyone actually needs to know what was changed when, they can look at the revision history.

Note that you shouldn't include the *reason* for an edit in the post *anywhere* in that post.  If you want to explain *why* you're making an edit, use the revision summary, which will be visible when looking at the revision history for that post.

Comment: Do they (one who comment) receive update notification?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** Servy's answer is pretty much what I stand behind and what I upvoted. I have just one addition which is my personal explanation for myself to accept why you don't want to add noise - and why we call the subject under discussion noise to begin with.

---

And it is simply this: questions and answers on Stackoverflow are **deliverables**.

Thinking about deliverables in IT-land, you think about documentation, actual software, reports, unit tests, etc. etc. Would you add chatty noise / status updates to those deliverables? Say the software you put in production has visible TODO notes in the page text and markers that state "added in version 1.2", or reports contain remarks to a colleague about possible mistakes in numbers that they need to investigate?

No - deliverables are as clean as they can be and only contain what they need to contain as part of the requirements and specifications bound to them. Anything else you put in the proper place; issue trackers, versioning system change comments, wiki documentation, code comments, email, etc.

Treat questions and answers on Stackoverflow exactly the same; they're the product we're all building together. As such a question contains only the question (and anything that goes with it), an answer contains only the answer. Direct communication with other people, status updates, version history, gratitude, etc. etc. have no place in them; that's what the comments, the voting system and the change history that the site maintains are for.

Comment: Great analogy gimby...